# How can I add a letter onto the end of a character array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am trying to make a program in c++, and I need to add a character to the end of a character array. In java it would look something like this:

```
arr[arr.length] = 'C';
```

or

```
str += "C";
```

but how could I add a character to the end of and already existing array of characters? any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying to manipulate strings, use `std::string` instead of `char[]`. If you're trying to learn about arrays in C++, create a longer array, copy the contents and add the new element. (I seem to be one of the only people around here who thinks that it's important to learn to use arrays before delegating them to the standard containers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using C++ use `std:string`. Then it works as you expect.

```
std::string s("a test string");
s += " with appended data";

OR

std::string s("a test string");
s += '!'; // Append single character
```

Answer (score 5):

**Important to note:** *Arrays are fixed in size.*

Perhaps you would like to use `std::string`?

```
std::string yourString = "...";
yourString += 'C';
```

If you really need the C-style string (similar to a char array) use `.c_str()`.

```
yourString.c_str();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want something that models a character string, then you'd use an [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of an array, and you'd do something like

```
s += 'C';
```

where `s` is the `std::string`. For example,

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s = "abcdefgh";
  s += 'C';
}
```

If you want something more like a buffer of `char`, you can use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<char> v = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

You can add elements to the end using `push_back()`:

```
v.push_back('C');
```